# Is it possible to create "List<SomeClass> obj" with in class name "SomeClass"

Tags: java, performance

```
class SomeClass{
 List<Someclass> list=new ArrayList<SomeClass>();//getter and setters
}
```

In above class, i have created the List object of same class objects. I want to know the impact of above code and if it is ok to have, I have doubt about its recursion impact ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle problem that can cause baffling errors if you do the wrong thing, however.  Suppose you try to design a class so it keeps track of all objects in that class:

```
public class Book {
    private static final List<Book> LIBRARY = new ArrayList<>();
    private String dewey;
    private String isbn;
    private String author;
    private String title;
    public Book(String dewey, String isbn, String author, String title) {
        this.dewey = dewey;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        LIBRARY.add(this);
    }

    public static final List<Book> getLibrary() {
        return LIBRARY;
    }
}
```

This class is dangerous, as it allows a reference to `this` to escape the object before the constructor completes.

1. The compiler is allowed to reorder the statements in the constructor as it wishes, since they are all independent.
2. Somebody could have grabbed a copy of LIBRARY before you call the constructor, and a getLibrary call may get access to LIBRARY before the `Book` object is fully usable.  Anything can happen then.

Also, the Composite pattern is similar to your idea.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I got the point But this could be solved with synchronization, right??

Answer (score 4):

The definition of `List<T>` is not dependent on the structure of T.  The information is used by the compiler to only allow adding objects of type T and when you retrieve it automatically convert the return value to the appropriate type.  So it is fine to have the List definition in the same class.

The list only contains references to objects of type T.  If the complete object were to be allocated and stored as part of the list it would have caused problems.

Comment: so you mean when i initialize list=new ArrayList<SomeClass>(); and try to access list then it will be fine and no memory leaks.

Comment: Yes it is fine - list = new ArrayList<SomeClass>() only allocates space to store references to objects of SomeClass, it is not creating any instance of SomeClass.

Comment: gkamal, but when i assign or store the objects in list, will you support your statement.

Comment: Yes it will not be a problem.  When all the references to the main object go out of scope that object and the ones in the list are garbage collection.  The only thing you should not do is put the reference of this object into the collection - that will create a cyclic reference and cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it no problem.

There is no recursion problem because none of your class instances are created when the List is created - using your class name is only the *type* of the List.

Answer (score 0):

simply use....

```
class SimpleClass
{
String var1;
int var2;
double var3;
}
```

implement all getter and setter for these variable so its will become a datatype for your list object.

now for storing object of this class use SimpleClassMgr

```
class SimpleClassMgr 
{
//this is your list where you will store object
List<Someclass> list=new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
```

make methods for add().delete(),update(),get() to insert and alter your records
 for example

```
public void add()
{
list.add(simpleclassobject);

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Akash, But I want to know the other way around.

Comment: the way i asked my question.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a tree of SomeClass objects. As long as you are OK with having leafs with empty lists it is no problem. You might want to look into having null instead of the list for better memory efficiency.